# NancyFX HEAD verb causing connection reset

Tags: c#, nancy

I am having problems using fulfilling HEAD requests in NancyFX (0.23.2).  I am using Nancy self-hosting and GET works fine, but HEAD just causes a dropped connection.  From debugging the source, it seems that an exception is being thrown at NancyHost.OutputWithDefaultTransferEncoding (line 321), with additional information "An operation was attempted on a non-existent network connection"

Do I need to do anything special to support HEAD?

Thanks,

Jon

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var hostConfiguration = new HostConfiguration();
        hostConfiguration.UrlReservations.CreateAutomatically = true;
        var _host = new NancyHost(hostConfiguration, new Uri("http://localhost:1010"));
        _host.Start();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Module : NancyModule
{
    public Module()
    {
        Get["/"] = x =>
        {
            return 201;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Probably.  I filed a nancy bug report, and got an emailrecently from @jorgb that its probably related to chunked encoding as per https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/1337